# jquery select2 keep placeholder on select

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using Select2: https://select2.org/

I would like to placeholder to remain always visible even when I select something. I will use selected data, but I want placeholder to be there always. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
templateSelection: function () {
    return 'placeholder';
}
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to work, it only creates a new selection with word 'placeholder'.

Comment: @Toniq Can you show your code